# Should we create synonyms for credit-score as credit-report tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are 2 tags  [credit-score](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-score) and [credit-report](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-report).
Technically the report is the overall letter and score is the number.
But is the distinction required, should we be creating synonyms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A credit report provides **detail**.  The score, on the other hand, provides a number score as a summary.  I suggest the two tags be maintained *separately*, not as synonyms, since report vs. score are distinct concepts, even though there's a relationship.

Comment: +1 They are different and the distinction is lost on many people when it shouldn't be!